# Digital zoom disabled on other modes except C2 - Canon G1X

Tags: compact-cameras, canon-g1-x, digital-zoom

I'm new to photography and I've researhed about this over google and can't find the exact answer on this. I've read that the Digital Zoom option on Canon G1X should be enabled when you choose JPG as the file format for shooting but thats not the case on my end.

Ive already tried setting JPG as the format, and thats my default, but I still can't enable Digital Zoom from the settings menu. The only way I have access to it is when I set the mode dial to C2, which is Custom.

[image: settings]

[image: lcd]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C2 is basically just a snapshot of the settings that were active in the camera when you chose to save that state as a "Custom" setting. If your camera won't do something in any of the other modes now that it will do in C2 it just means the applicable setting has been changed since the time the current C2 profile was recorded.

The basic menu option to enable or disable *Digital Zoom* is found by pressing the *Menu button*, navigating to the *Shooting* tab (the one with the camera symbol) and selecting *Digital Zoom*. You can then select from *Standard* or *Off*.

As outlined on pages 230-231 of the [*Powershot G1 X Camera User Guide*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300006975/01/psg1x-cug-c-en-web.pdf), digital zoom is only available in certain shooting modes and not available in others. It is *not* available in the following shooting modes: SCN-High Speed Burst HQ, SCN-Handheld Night Scene, SCN-Stitch Assist, or *any* of the Image Effects (Creative Filters) modes.

There are other notes spread throughout the *User Guide* that describe certain features that are not available when other menu items are selected. A thorough reading of the *User Guide* after a problem is encountered is sometimes needed to find and isolated note that tells of the limitation.

One such note on page 56 says that digital zoom is only available when the 4:3 aspect ratio is selected. If any other aspect ratio is selected digital zoom is not available.

Comment: From page 51 of the *Powershot G1 X Camera User Guide*: "To deactivate digital zoom, press the menu button, choose [Digital Zoom] on the *(camera symbol)* tab, and then choose [Off]."   http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300006975/01/psg1x-cug-c-en-web.pdf

Comment: Yes but that's my problem. It is not enabled or it can't be selected. It's there but it's not available to be selected. It can only be chosen under Custom.

Comment: solved it! I needed to switch to 4:3 size and it can now be selected in settings!

Comment: Yeah, it says so right on page 56 of your *User Guide*.

Comment: Let's have the answer in an answer.  Either Cisco you can add an answer or Michael update his to include the 4:3 aspect ration being required.